# How to change state of parent component with radio button in child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React this week and I'm trying to make a soundboard. I was able to make the soundboard work, but I wanted to be able to change the sounds for each key with a radio button.

I've looked up a ton of stackoverflow questions to try but I still can't get it to work. I've also tried console logging everything out and checking the dev tools but still no luck. I could be going about this the complete wrong way but I'm just not very familiar with React yet so I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Essentially what I'm trying to do is change between 2 different sound options [sounds.sound1 & sounds.sound2]

**APP.JS:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Pad from "./Pad";
import SoundSelector from "./SoundSelector";
import sounds from "./sounds";


    class App extends Component {
    state = {
    first808: sounds.sound1,
  };

  handleFirst808Change = e => {

    const first808 = { ...this.state.first808 };
    console.log("changed");
    console.log(this.state.first808);
    this.setState({ first808: e.target.value });
    this.setState({ first808: first808 });
  };

  handleKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.key === "a") {
      console.log("a has been pressed");
      const audio = new Audio(`${this.state.first808.audio}`);
      audio.loop = false;
      audio.play();
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="controller">
        <Pad handleKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />

        <SoundSelector
          sounds={this.state}
          handleFirst808Change={this.handleFirst808Change}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SOUNDSELECTOR.JS**

```
import React from "react";

class SoundSelector extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sound-selector">
        <h2>Choose Sounds</h2>

        <div className="first-808">
          <h3>First 808</h3>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              onChange={this.props.handleFirst808Change}
              value={this.props.sounds.sound1}
              name="first-808"
            />
            Option 1
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              onChange={this.props.handleFirst808Change}
              value={this.props.sounds.sound2}
              name="first-808"
            />
            Option 2
          </label>
        </div>
}

export default SoundSelector;
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem?

Comment: @qjnr the state isn't changing -- so when i change the radio buttons the default sound still plays when i press the key

Comment: can you try `onChange={() => this.props.handleFirst808Change()}`

Comment: Why are you setting the state twice ?

Comment: @akcoban I dont see that what you suggested would change anything and you are now ignoring the event parameter

Comment: @Kabbany oops, i didn't mean to! i took out `this.setState({ first808: first808 });` and now i'm getting `Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.`

Comment: First I dont see sounds in the state and you are passing it as a prop to the child component. Second I would suggest adding a new state called selectedSound which is an index in your case it should be 0 or 1 since you have two sounds. The value of radio button button should be 0 and 1 respectively. onChange set selectedSound in the state of the parent component to the value of the radio button (0 or 1). Then you can play the sound you want depending on selectedSound. Something like this.sounds[this.state.selectedSound]

Comment: @1999wildfire by the way `handleKeyDown` is missing closing bracket

Comment: @Kabbany i feel like a total idiot :( lol i thought i was passing it this whole time but i clearly was not. thank you for pointing that out!